# JS RandomColor Change on hover

Tags: javascript, html, colors

I want to change the color randomly on hovering `<a class="c-link"`
but it doesn't work and I wonder what I am doing wrong here.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    function randomColor() {
      let color = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        color.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
      }
      return 'rgb(' + color.join(', ') + ')';
    }

    document.querySelector('c-link').addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
      document.a.style.fontcolor = randomColor();
    });
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="c-text__layer">
    <div class="c-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur,<br> sadipscing elitr,
      <a class="c-link" href="https://stackoverflow.com/"> sit amet dolor</a></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please mark it as "accepted". Otherwise, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the class with a `.` within the query selector. Therefore `querySelector('.c-link')`.

You cannot just call `document.a` because `a` is not a property or method of the `document` object.

Also, there is `style.color` and `style.font` but not `fontcolor`.

Instead use another selector: `querySelector('a')` to select all the anchors in the document. This will affect every link though. If you only want it to work for one or a few elements you could use the `data-attribute`, an `id` or even other CSS classes instead of targeting `a` in the querySelector.

You can also read a bit on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) to learn more about JS and the web.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    function randomColor() {
      let color = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        color.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
      }
      return 'rgb(' + color.join(', ') + ')';
    }

    document.querySelector('.c-link').addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
      document.querySelector('a').style.color = randomColor();
    });
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="c-text__layer">
    <div class="c-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur,<br> sadipscing elitr,
      <a class="c-link" href="https://stackoverflow.com/"> sit amet dolor</a></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```